# What does expand doing in the query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am new in LINQ.

I have following query, I dont know, what it is representing.

```
  var query = (from p in data.First
                                 .Expand("Second")
                                 .Expand("Second/Third")
                                 .Expand("Second/Third/Forth")
                                 .Expand("Second/Fifth")
                     where p.Second.Third.Property1== "name"
                     select p);
```

can anyone explain?

Comment: what type of object is data here?

Comment: its a DataServiceContaxt object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely WCF Data Services and is for eagerly loading related data - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679728.aspx.

It adds the $expand query option to the generated uri. See http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#ExpandSystemQueryOption for more details.

Comment: I would read the linked articles, and inspect the URI that is being outputted, and run this directly in the browser to inspect the results of the query.